# How to run a snmp simulator for multiple agents?

Tags: snmp, pysnmp

I am running a snmpsimd.py command with a specific ip and port and a data directory.But i am not getting any response?
how to have multiple agents?
When we are specifying data directory how to separates which snmprec file belongs to which agents?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at snmpsimd startup logging - it should note all data files it finds and which SNMP v1/v2c community corresponds to each of them.

In general, each data file path (relative to the data directory) serves as SNMP community or SNMPv3 context) name.

The [documentation](http://snmplabs.com/snmpsim/addressing-agents.html) should explain that in greater details.